# change the image background of a button when it's clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I put an input button, and set its background with an image, now Ii want to change that image when the button is clicked.

Here is my relevant code:

```
<div id='back'>
    <input type="button"/>
</div>
```

***CSS*** code:

```css
#back input{
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    background: url(img/back_default.png);
    border: hidden;
}
```

Can it be done in CSS (as with links-`<a>` tags), or should I rely to JavaScript instead? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the background to change only during the click or from then on?

Comment: @Phil: Only during the click, as long as i hold mouse click on the button.

Comment: @Malloc Then see Matt's answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript is not needed:

```css
#back input {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    background: url(img/back_default.png);
    border: hidden;
}

#back input:active {
    background-image: url(img/back_default-active.png);
}
```

Comment: Good call, removed incorrect information about input type attributes.

Comment: Yes, i was about writing you, `input` instead `button`. You anticipated me :) - That works great, thanx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work with JavaScript:

```
function change() { 
    document.
        getElementById("back").
        getElementsByTagName("input").
        style.backgroundImage = "url(img/anotherImage.png)"
}
```

Call it from your button click (or from anywhere you want):

```
<div id='back'>
    <input type="button" onclick="change()"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as Matt Said you could use CSS's active pseudo class to change the background or alternatively you could use javascript to add an eventHandler (onClick Listner )to the button that changes the image.

**HTML**

```
<div id='back'>
     <input type="button" id="xyz" value="Go to back" class="button"/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>

el = document.getElementById('xyz');
el.addEvenListener("click",changeImg,false);

function changeImg()
{
    el = document.getElementById('xyz');
    el.style.backround="url('img/back_default-active.png')";
}

</script>
```